# navigation bar not show when i drag to show another page

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

first i use the PAGGING library

https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

i found that it's the problem , when i connect any button to show another controller it it navigate me to that controller but the navigation not shown , for example back button

i try many solutions and non of them work for example i try to make the menu manual  but the back button show but not work

i create button and connect to this action

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

didn't work

Comment: share some piece of code to help us to help u

Comment: Can you show us what the screen looks like where the "navigation" is missing? That might tell us more about what the problem is.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/F7VgLr6.png

Comment: That's interesting, it seems like you set it up well. What if you put `self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false` in your `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: no , i said the problem it show cuz the Home View Controller in parent of controller , the problem from the PageMenu

try to download example and connect any button inside this pages to show another controller , it won't show

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Does using the library you mentioned cause problems? Then maybe you're not implementing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a pushViewController first. Ensure that you are displaying your viewcontrollers through push.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

You do not need to code anything to display the previous controller when you have push.

Comment: its not the same. your code is popViewController. Mine is pushViewController. changing the code does it solve your problem?

Comment: @jo3birdtalk I think OP meant he used `popViewController` to go to the previous page, not to the next.

Comment: @Tim Vermeulen , yes

Comment: I see. did you happen hide your navigation bar? try `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false` inside `viewDidLoad` method